# How work with SQL and multiple join or merge them

Tags: mariadb, many-to-many

I need to retrieve events from table, with skills requirements and user engagements and skills.

For a project, I have :

- an users table
- a skills table with inheritance from others skills
- an users_skills table with skills of users
- an events table
- an events_skills table with the quantity of a required skills for the events
- an events_users table with users engagements on events

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` char(32) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `skills` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` char(64) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `skills` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `users_skills` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `skill_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`skill_id`) REFERENCES `skills` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` char(64) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `events_skills` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `event_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `skill_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `quantity` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `events` (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`skill_id`) REFERENCES `skills` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `events_users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `event_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `events` (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
);
```

I want to retrieve all events, with skills requirments and users participation.

My first idea was to use LEFT JOIN :

```
SELECT  e.id, e.name, es.skill_id, s.name skill_name, es.quantity,
        eu.user_id, u.name user_name, us.skill_id user_skill_id,
        uss.name user_skill_name
    FROM  events e
    LEFT JOIN  events_skills es  ON es.event_id = e.id
    LEFT JOIN  skills s  ON s.id = es.skill_id
    LEFT JOIN  events_users eu  ON eu.event_id = e.id
    LEFT JOIN  users u  ON u.id = eu.user_id
    LEFT JOIN  users_skills us  ON us.user_id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN  skills uss  ON uss.id = us.skill_id;

id  name    skill_id    skill_name  quantity    user_id user_name   user_skill_id   user_skill_name
1   eve1    2           ski2        3           1       use1        2               ski2
1   eve1    3           ski2-2      1           1       use1        2               ski2
1   eve1    2           ski2        3           2       use2        NULL            NULL
1   eve1    3           ski2-2      1           2       use2        NULL            NULL
2   eve2    NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL    NULL        NULL            NULL
```

2 differents events, second without users and skills. First, with 2 users, first with one skills, seconds without skills, and finally, two skills requirements.

It work "fine", but it's verry ugly, and I think it can be very slow if an event or an user has too many skills.
Also, each event has a lot of lines, and it's difficult to sort them (if I want to display only 20 events...).

To improve, I think I can load all skills separately and remove the two LEFT JOIN for table skills.

But, can I merge all skills and quantity in one column, and users in others ? Did you have betters solutions/improvements ?

```
id  name    skills  users
1   eve1    2,3;3,1 1,2;2,NULL
2   eve2    NULL    NULL
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do what Thorsten suggested:

```
select  e.*, 
        ( SELECT  group_concat(skill_id order by  skill_id separator ',')
            from  events_skills
            WHERE  event_id = e.id 
        ) AS skills, 
        ( SELECT  group_concat(user_id order by  user_id separator ',' )
            from  events_users
            WHERE  event_id = e.id 
        ) AS users
    from  events e
    order by  e.id;
```

Each subquery needs an extra join to get the "name" of the skill and user instead of the "id".

May I suggest you use the name of the skill as its id.

When you have a many-many mapping table, be sure to use the pair of `ids` as the `PRIMARY KEY` and have an `INDEX` in the opposite order.  And don't have an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: Thank's. What's about performance? If I understand, sub select are done for every lines. If I have big tables and I want all events table, it can be slower than 'Thorsten Kettner', but if I want only few lines, it can be better?

Comment: @Lortet - Oops, I forgot to advise on indexes.  See addition.  As for which is faster, try them both.  (It probably depends on which version of MariaDB you are using.)

Answer (score 1):

A result with skills and users as comma-separated strings is exactly how I would do this, too. Use `GROUP_CONCAT` for this.

```
select e.*, s.skills, u.users
from events e
left join
(
  select event_id, group_concat(skill_id order by skill_id separator ',') as skills
  from events_skills
  group by event_id
) s on s.event_id = e.id
left join
(
  select event_id, group_concat(user_id order by user_id separator ',') as users
  from events_users
  group by event_id
) u on u.event_id = e.id
order by e.id;
```

Comment: Thank's. What's about performance? If I understand, join select are done only once, but with all data from table. If I have big tables, but I want all events table, it can be faster than 'Rock James', but if I want only few lines, it can be slower?

Comment: It depends very much on the DBMS which version is faster. The perfect DBMS would see that both queries select exactly the same data, so it would come up with the same execution plan for both. But yes, it may very well be that my query is faster on the whole table and Rick's on few rows. Just try. Apart from this, don't worry too much about performance. I don't expect a huge difference when running the queries. So, decide for the one you like better from the look and feel :-) None is really better than the other, that's just two different valid approaches.

Comment: @Lortet - in _old_ versions of MySQL/MariaDB, `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... )` would repeatedly evaluate the subquery.  Really bad.  But in today's versions, it is probably a toss-up between Thorsten and Rick.